# Python: group a list basing on pairs of items

Tags: python, algorithm, list

My program generates lists like this:

```
mydata = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux", "quid", "quo"]
```

And I know from other data that these can be grouped in couples (here a list of tuples, but can be changed to whatever):

```
static_mapping = [("foo", "quo"), ("baz", "quux"), ("quid", "bar")]
```

There's no ordering in the couples.

Now on to the problem: my program generates `mydata` and I need to group  data **by couple** but **keeping** a separate list of non-matched items. The reason is that at any moment `mydata` may *not* contain all items that are part of the couples.

Expected results on such a hypothetical function:

```
 mydata = ["foo", "bar", "quo", "baz"]
 couples, remainder = group_and_split(mydata, static_mapping)
 print(couples)
 [("foo", "quo")]
 print(remainder)
 ["bar", "baz"]
```

EDIT: Examples of what I've tried (but they stop at finding the coupling):

```
found_pairs = list()
for coupling in static_mapping:
    pairs = set(mydata).intersect(set(coupling))
    if not pairs or len(pairs) != 2:
        continue
    found_pairs.append(pairs)
```

I got stuck at finding a reliable way to get the reminder out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your implementation of this hypothetical function. Make it real!

Comment: What did you try yet? I dont get your actual Question.

Comment: there are many ways to do that. And depends on the mechanics of your grouping process. If you want to do it separately, after grouping has been already done, you can use `sets` to calculate the difference between the full collection and the items used (you should flat the list of tuples for that)

Comment: I worked with sers, but I could only get the mappings, not the remainder. I'll add the implementation.

Comment: @Einar See my answer. This way you can decouple the pairing process from the calculation of the remainder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
import copy

def group_and_split(mydata, static_mapping):
    remainder = copy.deepcopy(mydata)
    couples = []
    for couple in static_mapping:
        if couple[0] in mydata and couple[1] in mydata:
            remainder.remove(couple[0])
            remainder.remove(couple[1])
            couples.append(couple)
    return [couples, remainder]
```

Comment: You're making `remainder` merely an alias of `mydata`; the input does get modified! Copy it instead.

Comment: I can live without sets as the data are never too big to be an issue.

Comment: @Einar, *never* is always a very long period when talking about data.

Comment: That 'deepcopy' really eats up processing time. Will `remainder = list(mydata)` not be enough to do the copy?

Comment: @PaulRooney A deep copy isn't really necessary or is even the wrong construct to use. If you were splitting lists of lists, you'd expect the inner lists to remain the same and not copies. Only the outer list matters. In that case the basic copy construct or calling `list` should be equivalent as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Set gives you faster runtime if values are big, but takes memory, and deepcopy keeps the original data intact.

One of the implementations of the hypothetical functions could be :-

```
from copy import deepcopy

def group_and_split(mydata, static_mapping):
        temp  = set(mydata)
        couples = []
        remainder = deepcopy(mydata)
        for value1,value2 in static_mapping:
                if value1 in temp and value2 in temp:
                        couples.append((value1,value2))
                        remainder.remove(value1)
                        remainder.remove(value2)
        return couples, remainder
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Here you have how to do it with `sets` using `symmetric_difference` function:

```
>>> full =  ["foo", "quo", "baz", "quux", "quid", "bar", 'newone', 'anotherone']
>>> couples = [("foo", "quo"), ("baz", "quux"), ("quid", "bar")]

## now for the remainder. Note you have to flatten your couples:
>>> set(full).symmetric_difference([item for sublist in couples for item in sublist])
set(['anotherone', 'newone'])
>>>
```